# Como enviar authorization por header logout POST angular

Tags: java, angular, spring, tokens, headers

Estoy hace dias intentando cerrar sesion enviando el token desde angular en el header y no pude lograr nada aun, mi codigo en postman funciona perfectamente, pero aqui me tira el error. Mi back esta montado en JAVA Spring y el front con angular.

Dejo mi codigo front y back.

**Servicio Front end**

````
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LogoutComponent } from '../components/logout/logout.component';
import { JwtInterceptorInterceptor } from '../utils/jwt-interceptor.interceptor';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LogoutService {
  
 private url:string= "http://localhost:8080/auth";
 
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {

   }

  public logOut():any{
    let headers = new Headers({
      'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken'),
      'Content-type' : 'application/json',
    })
    return this.http.post(this.url + "/logout", {header:headers});
    }
   
  } ```

**Controlador Back end**

```     @PostMapping("/logout")
    public ResponseEntity<?> logout() {
        try {
            String username = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
            User user = userServ.findByUsername(username);
            user.setOnline(false);
            userServ.saveUser(user);
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            return new ResponseEntity<> ("Logout successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            throw new RequestException("No user conected", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "P-300");
        }
    }```

Al mandar el token desde el sessionStorage, me da la excepcion creada 'User not found'.
Agradezco su ayuda.
Gracias.
Saludos
````

Answer (score 0):

La firma del metodo `post` del `HttpClient` es la siguiente:

```
httpClient.post(url, body, options)
```

Por lo que para que te funcionen los headers, tienes que mover el objeto de opciones al 3er argumento de la llamada.

```
this.http.post(this.url + "/logout", null, { headers });
```

un saludo

Comment: Hola amigo. Muchas gracias! Lo habia solucionado seteandolo, pero voy a probar asi.